How is this view being done in ARKit?
I am new to iOS development and have been trying to replicate this view from ARKit. I have a 3rd party app that shows this image of my TV.
I am not sure if I should be using SceneKit or ARKit for this. The goal is to open my app and have everything look in the view of the screenshot I attached where I can identify my TV.
If someone can please point me in the right direction of what this is called or which framework I should be using that would be greatly appreciated!

